# How to recover deleted Windows 10 service executable

Tags: windows-10, services

Recently I deleted sppsvc.exe file located in windows/system32 directory, it is Software Protection Service file. Because of that, my office and windows are no longer activated. Is there any way to recover sppsvc.exe without reinstalling Windows 10?

I already tried putting in system32 sppsvc.exe that I downloaded from one of those dll-downloading sites but I get error "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file..."

Comment: From an elevated command prompt, try running `SFC /SCANNOW`, let that run, reboot, and then see if it's back. Let me know if that helps you any.

Comment: @Walmart Thank you very much, That command did system scan and downloaded sppsvc.exe and generated Log file. Feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Dragon - I just added the answer, I'm glad to help and glad to hear your issue is resolved.

Comment: What possessed you to do a thing like that!?!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @MosheKatz I started using process explorer instead of task manager recently, and whenever I was doing anything I saw sppsvc.exe turn on and turn off, over and over again. I tried disabling it from Task scheduler but that didn't work, disabling it in services didn't work either, it kept turning on/off so I decided I would delete it, what could go wrong, right? :D

Comment: @Dragon LOL--well you learned a good lesson.  *Next* time hit up Google first to see what you might be putting in the Trash Can.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Is there any way to recover `sppsvc.exe` without reinstalling Windows 10?**

From an elevated command prompt, run `SFC /SCANNOW`, let that run and finish, reboot the OS aftewards, and that should get the missing system file loaded back onto the OS.

---

### Further Resources

[System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files)